# java - Insert fail when using Spring, hibernate and JPA with JBOSS 7.1 server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactional

I'm trying to set up the hibernate + JPA on my project. but when I try to do an insert nothing happens, I go into the source code of hibernate jars and I see that hibernate it's recognizing my entity as TRANSIENT state and not as PERSISTENT.

Some of my configuration is:

My Spring context:

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="integrationDS" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/integrationDS" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="integrationDS" />
</bean>
```

My persistence xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="integrationDS">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/integrationDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.integration.domain</class>
    <class>com.integration.domain.myentity</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="none" />
        <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100"/>
        <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.integration.util.MysqlBitBooleanDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My code:

```
    @Transactional
    public <T> T executeSaveInTransaction(T entity) {

    try {
        getDao().persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        //rollbackTransaction();
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //rollbackTransaction();
        throw new DaoException(e);
    } finally {
        // clear resources
    }
}
```

any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: do you have `<tx:annotation-driven >` configured for enabling @Transactional

Comment: I was trying whit: <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
     <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />

 </bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />


but when I do that I get problems with spring injection

Answer (score 0):

What is the location of persistence.xml? Basically are you sure it is being read as you have not provide a reference to persistence.xml in your spring context.